# PHP Search System that reads .txt and outputs every line that has a specific string in it

Tags: php

So I have this site where I want to create a listing of best torrent Magnet URI alternatives.
I'd rather list everything from some .html file:

```
<a href="torrent1:magnet:uri">torrent1:name_of_torrent</a>
<a href="torrent2:magnet:uri">torrent2:name_of-torrent</a>
...
```

and have PHP check for the $_POST['search_torrent'] and search that data inside the .html, if any of the specific data/name was found in any of those lines, then output that entire line as a **item** using **foreach()**.

I did something like this, but the host I'm trying to accomplish this on doesn't allow **exec()** nor **shell_exec()**.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search_torrent'])) {
    $search_torrent = $_POST['search_torrent'];
    $torrent_file = "read.txt";

    echo nl2br(shell_exec("type ".$torrent_file."| find /I \"".$search_torrent."\""));
?>
```

[image: Search Example]

I know I know... I could use database but I'm just not into that at this moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file lines into an array and grep that:

```
foreach(preg_grep('/'.preg_quote($_POST['search_torrent'], '/').'/i', file('read.txt')) as $line) {
    echo "$line<br>";
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. I'll accept the answer in 9 minutes 